# How to select free wheeling ultra fast recovery diode for 30VDC coil with 10 amperes of current

Tags: diodes

How do I select an ultra fast recovery diode for switching circuit of 30VDC coil having 10 amperes of current?
The coil is switched ON by an N-channel MOSFET.

- 20 milli seconds ON
- 300 milli seconds OFF

Comment: Is that a \$60\:\text{mH}\$ inductor?

Answer (score 1):

Selecting flywheel diode:

Voltage rating should be at least two times the supply voltage.  For your case , use diode rating of least 60V.

Current rating should be at least 1.5 times load current. So if use 10A load then use 15A diode.

Also here is an example device MBR1660

Comment: Please guide any calculation for selection of Fast recovery diode , Can UF 5408 works